# Using Objective-C delegation in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates

I'm trying to implement an Objective-C delegation into my swift class but I keep getting

```
Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol
```

This is my Objective-C class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>


@protocol BT_BLE_LibDelegate;
@interface BT_BLE_Lib : NSObject< CBCentralManagerDelegate>
{
    NSObject<BT_BLE_LibDelegate> __weak *delegate;
    NSError *BTError;
    int BLEMode;
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BT_BLE_LibDelegate> __weak delegate;
- (void) UARTSend:(NSString*)message;         //  UART 送到藍芽
- (int)  iBeaconStartScan;                    //  找 iBeacon
- (int)  iBeaconStopScan;                     //  停止 iBeacon
- (int)  ConnectBlueTooth;                    //  連接藍芽
- (int)  BlueToothConnectStatus;              //  藍芽連接情況
- (void) DigitalOuts:(NSString*)sender;       //  藍芽接腳數位輸出
- (void) DigitalInput;                        //  藍芽接腳數位輸入
@end

@protocol BT_BLE_LibDelegate
- (void) BlueToothStatus:(NSString*)errorMsg;  // 取的HW 藍牙的連接情況

- (void) DidReceiveData:(NSString*)message;    // 收到資料

- (void) DidReadHardwareRevisionString:(NSString*)Msg;  // 硬體相關的訊息
- (void) DigitalInputPinsChanges:(NSString*)Msg;    // 數位輸入的情況改變
- (void) DidReceiveiBeacon:(NSString*)Name  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI Action:(NSString*)Action;                         // iBeacon 的情況
@end
```

And this is my Swift class

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , BT_BLE_LibDelegate{

var myObj : BT_BLE_Lib?
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    myObj = BT_BLE_Lib()
    myObj?.delegate = self

}

func DidReceiveData(message: NSString?) {
    
}

func BlueToothStatus(errorMsg: NSString?) {
    
}// 取的HW 藍牙的連接情況

func DidReadHardwareRevisionString(Msg: NSString?) {
    
}// 硬體相關的訊息
func DigitalInputPinsChanges(Msg: NSString?) {
    
}// 數位輸入的情況改變
func DidReceiveiBeacon(Name: NSString?, RSSI: Int, Action: NSString?) {
    
}
```

Note: I tried to add _ before the parameters name or adding -> void after the function but same result

---

Ok I found a solution
I just replaced NSString with String!

```
    public func didReceiveiBeacon(_ Name: String!, rssi RSSI: NSNumber!, action Action: String!)
```

Now I have no syntax error..
but the method is not working (I used debugger)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the images with actual copy and pasted code.

Comment: ok.. done......

Comment: You have declared your Swift functions as receiving an optional, but you haven't set he nullability on the Objective C side

Comment: Try to replace Int with NSNumber

Comment: Paulw11 .. Im not sure I understand what you mean..

Comment: Avt.. I did it already

Answer (score 0):

You have used incorrect *camelCase* in naming your delegate methods in the Objective-C protocol, but Swift fixed this for you when it imported the protocol.  As a result your Swift delegate implementation needs to look like:

```
func didReceiveData(_ message: String?) {

}

func blueToothStatus(_ errorMsg: String?) {

}

func didReadHardwareRevisionString(_ Msg: String?) {

}

func digitalInputPinsChanges(_ Msg: String?) {

}

func didReceiveiBeacon(_ Name: String?, rssi RSSI: NSNumber, action Action: String?) {

}
```

Note the lower-case first letters.  I am also not sure if those parameters should be optional;  I would suggest you update your Objective-C protocol to use the correct naming and also to indicate the nullability or otherwise (`_Nonnull` or `_Nullable`) of the parameters.  Something like:

```
@protocol BT_BLE_LibDelegate
- (void) blueToothStatus:(NSString* _Nullable)errorMsg;  // 取的HW 藍牙的連接情況

- (void) didReceiveData:(NSString* _Nullable)message;    // 收到資料

- (void) didReadHardwareRevisionString: (NSString* _Nullable)Msg;  // 硬體相關的訊息
- (void) digitalInputPinsChanges:(NSString* _Nullable)Msg;    // 數位輸入的情況改變
- (void) didReceiveiBeacon:(NSString* _Nullable)Name  RSSI:(NSNumber * _Nonnull)RSSI Action:(NSString* _Nullable)Action;                         // iBeacon 的情況
@end
```

Also, on the subject of style, iOS uses camelCase, not pythonesque underscores, so your protocol should be something like `BtBLELibDelegate`

Comment: Well.. The objective-c class is from a framework that I'm using .. so can't change it

Comment: Ok, then just change your Swift method names to have a lowercase first letter and it will work.  Be sure to code defensively and unwrap those optionals correctly as the Objective-C signatures tell you nothing about whether those parameters will have values

Comment: I think the problem is within the framework .. because only one of the function works and its not even working properly Although its working fine in my Objective-c project.. Thanks anyway ..